# How to filter issues to show only the ones assigned to current sprint (version) in YouTrack?

Tags: youtrack

How to filter issues to show only the ones assigned to current sprint (version) in YouTracks' searchbar?

I can filter issues using the sprint name (e.g. "31.08 - 11.09"):

```
version: {31.08 - 11.09}
```

But I want to use a wildcard that corresponds to the current sprint - something like that:

```
version: {current}
```

I need this to create a report that I don't have to update for every sprint.

Answer (score 2):

Official YouTrack support:

> Hello thorinkor!
>
> Thank you for reaching out. Unfortunately, filtering by "current"
>   sprint is not possible. I'd suggest to use particular version name in
>   each report.
>
> Regards, AT YouTrack Engineer
>
> JetBrains http://www.jetbrains.com "Develop with pleasure!"

Any other ideas how can I achieve this? ;<